# What type of cocoa pod this is?

Tags: identification, planting

Does anyone know what type of cocoa this is? I live in a tropical country in Southeast asia. The pod originally has a green color and now its turning yellow or reddish in color. The surface of the pod is not smooth and the pod is not super skinny and not super round in shape.

Comment: A photograph would be useful.

Comment: In Taiwan?.......,